next/link does not prefetch when embedded in vite compiled package
I have a NextJS app that incorporates shared components from another repo which is built into a package via vite.
next/link instances inside the package do not prefetch when run inside the next app. The app is running in production mode, and I've verified prefetching works properly when I put the same link in the next app proper.
I've also got the package included in the transpilePackages option of next.config.js.
How can I get the next/link instances inside the shared package to prefetch as expected?

A code example might help. But from what i can see you might solve this by injecting the Link from your app to the components mentioned.

That's what I ended up doing as a workaround, but I'm curious if there is a way to get next/link to work as expected when used in a packaged library running in a nextjs app. If not, and there is sufficient proof, I'm cool with that too.
